# Service to trigger and run python scripts?

Tags: python, triggers

So far when dealing with web scraping projects, I've used GAppsScript, meaning that I can easily trigger the script to be run once a day.

Is there an equivalent service when dealing with python scripts? I have a RaspberryPi, so I guess I can keep it on 24/7 and use cronjobs to trigger the script daily. But that seems rather wasteful, since I'm talking about a few small scripts that take only a few seconds to run.

Is there any service that allows me to trigger a python script once a day? (without a need to keep a local machine on 24/7) The simpler the solution the better, wouldn't want to overengineer such a basic use case if a ready-made system already exists.

Answer (score 1):

The only service I've found so far to do this with is [WayScript](https://wayscript.com/) and [here's](https://wayscript.com/shared/K7UIc8WP) a python example running in the cloud. The free tier that should be enough for most simple/hobby-tier usecases.

Comment: Here is a link to the docs on how to run WayScript scheduled tasks: https://wsxdocs.wayscript.com/quickstart/schedule-a-task